# How to Use PHP output (return) inside htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm beginner in Htaccess.
I have a question, can i use a php output in htaccess?

example:

```
RewriteRule ^master/(PHP OUTPUT (userID if have permission))/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /download/$2.zip [L]
```

Sorry for bad english

Comment: No that is not possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .htaccess is parsed on webserver level, so even before any PHP or HTML is loaded. As no session is loaded yet, you cannot do any checking in the htaccess. The htaccess is also for everyone, not just one visitor, making the htaccess dynamic based on a user session through php will then be applied to any new visitor. Therefor you cannot make the htaccess dynamic. You will have to check rights and do dynamic redirection from within PHP.